# Count of rows scanned in a sql select query

Tags: mysql, database

Is there a way to know how many rows where actually scanned(not fetched) in a sql select query? I am trying to find out if number of rows scanned in sql select query when using index.

Comment: by using $no_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

Comment: Take a look at the information functions https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html

Comment: @MohitKumar A) That's PHP specific, not MySQL in general. B) That only talks about rows *returned*, not *examined*. A query might do a complete table scan and return zero rows.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to do this?

Comment: @SamM Just trying to do some comparison between aws-dynamo query and sql query.

Answer (score 2):

Prepend EXPLAIN to you query and the query plan will show that information

Comment: It'll give you a rough idea. Like a lot of things in MySQL it consists of wild speculation. Postgres, by comparison, gives a very detailed breakdown of what actually happened.

Answer (score 1):

Use,

EXPLAIN SELECT count(*) FROM table_name

Moreover, The value for the "rows" column in the EXPLAIN output is an estimate, and may not always be exact.

Refer,
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html#explain_rows